# How to do sorting on longitude and latitude, start with nearest and store into arraylist?

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have retrieve list of addresses.

```
ArrayList<LatLng> mPoints;
```

This is my function

```
String address;
String address1;
Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(con);
Address originAddr = addressList1.get(0);
Address destAddr   = addressList.get(0);
    for (int i=0;i<jobs.size();i++) {
        address = jobs.get(i).get("pick_address");
        address1 = jobs.get(i).get("delivery_address");
        List<Address> addrList2 = null;
        List<Address> addrList3 = null;

        try {
            addressList2 = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
            addressList3 = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address1, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address2 = addrList2.get(0);
        Address address3 = addrList3.get(0);

        LatLng location = new LatLng(address2.getLatitude(), address2.getLongitude());
        LatLng location1 = new LatLng(address3.getLatitude(), address3.getLongitude());

        mPoints.add(location);
        mPoints.add(location1);
    }
```

I want to store the sorted address into mPoints array list. Currently the address was unsorted.

How can i compare all of the address longitude and latitude, and then store the address nearest accordingly based on origin address?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the distance using Haversine Formula, then you insert it in an array then sort it from the closest distance.
For further reading, you can read this post: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: I know how the formula work, but i dunno how can i sort and display the lat and lng again.

Answer (score 0):

using this haversine formula you get the distance of particular addresses using that address lat-long you are able to store the data to 2 arrays 1 for the distance and another one for lat-long with distance so after that using collection sorting you are able to find the nearest distance and able to display that.